# Why is a vertical polygon defined by WKT PolygonZ invalid?

Tags: qgis, polygon, 3d, well-known-text, geos

Can you tell me, why this PolygonZ is invalid?

```
PolygonZ ((409662 5317369 285, 409662 5317377 285, 409662 5317377 302, 409662 5317369 302, 409662 5317369 285))
```

The polygon is completely vertical, but due to z coordinate points are not overlaying.

From GEOS validity checker I get the following error message:

```
Too few points in geometry component
```

The coordinates are in EPSG:32632 (WGS84/UTM Zone 32N)

Comment: Uhm but the polygon is not self intersecting?

Comment: It is intersecting in XY plane, maybe that is enough to generate errors.

Comment: No; its in XYZ coordinate (see Polygon Z)

Comment: It is interesting; This PolygonZ is valid: PolygonZ ((409662 5317369 285, 409662 5317377 285, 409662.0001 5317377.0001 302, 409662.0001 5317369.0001 302, 409662 5317369 285))

Comment: The PostGIS doc says for [st_isValid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html) - which is also computed by GEOS - _"Test if an ST_Geometry value is well-formed in 2D according to the OGC rules. [...] For geometries with 3 and 4 dimensions, the validity still only tested in 2 dimensions."_

Comment: PS: don't try st_makeValid on your example, the result is... surprising

Comment: thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1):

GEOS checks polygon validity in the XY plane only.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch the x-/y- and z-coordinates and run st_isValid to check the polygon seen from different directions (e.g. from -x and -y direction) if invalid seen from above…